# showing more info (onmouseover)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not sure how it's called in English , but i want the user to see more info when he hover's over an element in my table , something like this:

[image]

Only difference that the table look's like this:

[>>table<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7so3K.jpg)

And it should describe the content in more then one row , for example:

```
Molten Coin:
+17 Defenses
+11 Attacks
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-title

Comment: Thank you :) this is cool :D but is there a way to make a costume tooltip ? Like white background , bigger letters.

Comment: Then you'll have to emulate this behavior with JavaScript.

Comment: Or if you want to have more control on the tooltip, you could use an extension like: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Thank you all :) for now i'll stick with the classic .. since i am still learning jquery :D

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use a CSS tooltip:

```
    body {
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
    }

    .tooltipDiv {
        position:relative;
    }

    .tooltipDiv span {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:25px;
        left:60px;
        background-color:white;
        font-size:1.2em;
        color:black;
        padding:5px;
    }

    .tooltipDiv:hover span {
        display:inline;
}

<div class="tooltipDiv">
    My Area Div
    <span>Molten Coin:<br />+17 Defenses<br />+11 Attacks</span>
</div>
```

Check out the JSFiddle to see it in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMuvm/

Be aware though, if you use the :hover peudo class on anything other than an anchor element, you loose the compatibility with IE6. Take not of this paragraph from the MSDN site:

> Starting with Windows Internet Explorer 7, when the browser is in
>   standards-compliant mode (strict !DOCTYPE), you can apply the :hover
>   pseudo-class to any element, not only links. If the pseudo-class is
>   not applied specifically to an element in the selector, such as the a
>   tag, the Universal (*) Selector is assumed. Indiscriminate use of the
>   :hover pseudo-class can negatively impact page performance.

Can be viewed in context here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/cc848866(v=vs.85).aspx

A way to solve this, would be to put a block anchor element inside the DIV. Check out this fiddle for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uBF8J/

```
<div class="tooltipDiv">
    <a>My Area Div
        <span>Molten Coin:<br />+17 Defenses<br />+11 Attacks</span>
    </a>
</div>


body {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

.tooltipDiv a {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

.tooltipDiv a span {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:60px;
    background-color:white;
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:black;
    padding:5px;
}

.tooltipDiv a:hover span {
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery tooltip it will works fine 
take a look below url

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/
or
see below code

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip();
});
</script>
<style>
label {
display: inline-block;
width: 5em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#" title="That's what this widget is">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover
the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>
<p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
<a href="http://themeroller.com" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI's theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a>
will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
<p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
<p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." /></p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
</body>
</html>
```